# How can I add a new Windows Form and then add a PictureBox programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I'm looking to learn how to add a new form to my application programmatically & then add a picture box, text box, and a button to that new form?

I can add a new button, a new form, or a new picturebox on my current form but I can't seem to figure out how to add a new form to my application and then put the picturebox and textbox and the button on that new form.

What am I missing?

```
'Form2
Dim form2 As New Form
form2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 500)
form2.Show()
Dim picturebox1 As New PictureBox()
Dim Textbox1 As New TextBox()
Dim Button1 As New Button()
CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
Me.SuspendLayout()
'
'PICTURE BOX  PROPERTIES
'
picturebox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
picturebox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(11, 12)
picturebox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
picturebox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(365, 124)
picturebox1.TabIndex = 0
picturebox1.TabStop = False
picturebox1.Show()

'TEXTBOX PROPERTIES

Textbox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 142)
Textbox1.Name = "TextBox1"
Textbox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(364, 20)
Textbox1.TabIndex = 1
Textbox1.Show()


'BUTTON PROPERTIES
Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(128, 172)
Button1.Name = "Button1"
Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(95, 24)
Button1.TabIndex = 2
Button1.Text = "Submit"
Button1.Show()




Me.Controls.Add(picturebox1)
Me.Controls.Add(Textbox1)
Me.Controls.Add(Button1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try :

```
form2.Controls.Add(picturebox1)
form2.Controls.Add(Textbox1)
form2.Controls.Add(Button1)
```

This will show the `Control`s in the `form2`.